# How to keep the value of a variable despite function being called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I have a python function that will turn the servo to the left or right everytime a button on the web interface is clicked. Currently it is working like this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def turnCamera (self, **data):

    import pigpio
    import time

    servos=[4,7] #GPIO number
    pigpio.start()
    key = data['direction']
    if key=="left":
            servostatus = "left"
            print servostatus
            m=1500

    elif key=="right":
            servostatus = "right"
            print servostatus
            m=1000

    #to dispense pill
    if key=="dispense":
        m=900
        pigpio.set_servo_pulsewidth(servos[0], m) 
        servostat= "Position of servo: %s"%m
        print servostat
        time.sleep(1)
        m=1500
        pigpio.set_servo_pulsewidth(servos[0], m) 
        servostat= "Position of servo: %s"%m
        print servostat
        time.sleep(1)


    pigpio.stop()

    return servostat
```

The data is posted from jQuery:

```
$('#left_button').click(function(){
                        $.post('/turnCamera', {direction:"left"}).done(function (reply) {
                            $('#camerapos').empty().append(reply);
                            alert("left button clicked");});

                    });
                    $('#right_button').click(function(){
                        $.post('/turnCamera', {direction:"right"}).done(function (reply) {
                            $('#camerapos').empty().append(reply);
                            alert("right button clicked");});
                    });
```

However I would like the servo to turn such that each click will make it turns by 100. When the script is first run, it goes to initial position `m=1500`. Then user can control the camera position by clicking left or right. Something like this:

```
m=1500
while (m >= 500 and m <= 2500):
        if (key =="left"):
            m=m+100
        elif (key =="right"):
            m=m-100
```

However i do understand that this will not work because m will get reset to 1500 everytime the function is triggered (button is clicked). How can i store the value of m?

Comment: Store it into a database, or in a file on the server.

Comment: make the method `return [servostat, m]` and then change the method so that it has a parameter where you pass in the `m` from the previous call

Comment: @sshashank124 sounds like a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the method

`return [servostat, m]`

and then change the method so that it has a parameter where you pass in the m from the previous call like `def turnCamera(self, **data, m):`

As follows:

```
$('#left_button').click(function(){
                $.post('/turnCamera', {direction:"left",m_value:m}).done(function (reply) {
                    $('#camerapos').empty().append(reply);
                    alert("left button clicked");});
```

Comment: but where should i initialize the value of m?

Comment: @yvonnezoe, outside the method. possibly in your method that calls the `turnCamera`

Comment: that would be in a jQuery post?

Comment: Yes. wherever it is that you are calling the function from, just before that initialize the variable. Make sure that wherever you are initializing it that it will last for the whole process. So when you call the function, just pass it as a parameter and update its value as per the returned result from the method call.

Comment: i'm confused. :( can you show it in the answer? my jquery code is there too.

Comment: @yvonnezoe, Sorry for the long wait. There I updated it. So the `m` is the variable that you pass in and in your `python` script you get it as follows: `m = data['m_value']`